# Decrypt an encrypted mkey from a corrupt Bitcoin Core wallet.dat file

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, wallet-recovery

I have a 94 digit encrypted mkey that I obtained from my corrupted bitcoin core wallet.dat file.

I also have the password, the salt, and the number of iterations.

Using the password I’m unable to send bitcoins however I'm wondering if decrypting the encrypted mkey using my password, salt and iterations would allow me to decrypt my private key and have it in a usable wallet import format?  If that is possible, how would I do it?

Comment: Does [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/115046/how-do-ckey-mkey-and-the-private-key-fit-together-in-bitcoin) help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do ckey, mkey and the private key fit together in Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/115046/how-do-ckey-mkey-and-the-private-key-fit-together-in-bitcoin)